# Sessions not saving inside function call

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Inside my AuthController, I am doing the following:

```
request.post({url: 'https://graph.api.smartthings.com/oauth/token', form: authData} , function(err, resp, body){
    info = JSON.parse(body);
    req.session.accessToken = info.access_token;

    getEndpoint(req.session.accessToken, function(err, resp) {
        if(err) {
            //TODO: Handle error
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            req.session.endpointUri = resp;
        }
    });

    console.log("endpoint " + req.session.endpointUri);

    res.view('test', {
        accessToken: req.session.accessToken,
    });
});
```

As you can see, I am trying to set 2 sessions, accessToken and endpointUri.

The `accessToken` session saves just fine, and I can access it from other controllers, however my `endpointUri` does not save.
I've tested the function and resp is being returned, and if I log out the session straight after setting it within the else statement it works.

If I try and log out the session outside of the else statement, it is undefined.

What is happening here?

Comment: End point is setting on an async function, which is not completed when you return the view

Answer (score 2):

You want access the session value on an Async operation which is not completed when you return your view. Try:

```
request.post({url: 'https://graph.api.smartthings.com/oauth/token', form: authData} , function(err, resp, body){
    info = JSON.parse(body);
    req.session.accessToken = info.access_token;

    getEndpoint(req.session.accessToken, function(err, resp) {
    if(err) {
        //TODO: Handle error
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        req.session.endpointUri = resp;

        console.log("endpoint " + req.session.endpointUri);

        res.view('test', {
        accessToken: req.session.accessToken,
        });
    }
    });


});
```

By the way, this using nested callback is not the good pattern, try using bluebird library or asyncawait.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  How would I go about implementing what i've done using the async library?